# My program is crashing after I changed it. Reading from files

Tags: c, file, crash, linked-list

I am doing a project and when I try to use a file to help me keep recording the number of the register of a user.

After I had the part of creating a file, my program start crashing everytime I call a function that I changed (Ler_Pessoa()). It doesnt report any error or warning and I've not been able to understand why it's behaving like that.

I have two files, one is working correctly and I need the secound one to start in 0 everytime I delete the "Data.txt" file.

If you could take a look at my code, I would appreciate.

My header file:

```
#define ARQ "Dados.txt" /*ARQUIVO COM OS DADOS*/
#define ARQ_REG "Registo.txt" /*Arquivo que vai contabilizando o numero do registo */


FILE *fp;
FILE *reg;



typedef struct
{
    char Nome[100];
    int Sala;
    int Hora_inicio;
    int Minuto_inicio;
    int Hora_fim;
    int Minuto_fim;
    long int numero_registo;
    char Status; /* '*' Indica que o registo está apagado */
} PESSOA;


void Numero_Registo();
void Listar_Reservas();
void Apagar_Pessoa();
void Alterar_Pessoa();
void Inserir_Pessoa();
void Pesquisar_Nome(char *s);
void Iniciar();
void Ler_Pessoa(PESSOA *p);
void Mostrar_Pessoa(PESSOA p);
void Adicionar_Pessoa(PESSOA p);
void Mensagem(char *msg);
```

In Numero_Registo.c:

```
#include "header.h"

void Numero_Registo()    /*
                      * Verifica se o Arquivo REG já existe. Se não existir, o numero de registo começa a 0.
                      * Se já existir, abre-o em Modo de Leitura e Escrita (r+b)
                      */
{
    int i = 0;

    reg = fopen(ARQ_REG, "r+b"); /* Tenta Abrir*/
    if (reg==NULL)
    {
        reg=fopen(ARQ_REG, "w+b");
        fprintf("%d",i) ;/*Cria o Arquivo*/
    }
    fclose(reg);
}
```

In Ler_Pessoa.c:

```
#include "header.h"


void Ler_Pessoa(PESSOA *p) /*Esta função permite ler os dados inseridos por um utilizador de modo a fazer a reserva*/
{
    int num_reg;

    reg = fopen (ARQ_REG,"r");
    fscanf("%d", &num_reg);
    num_reg++;
    fclose(reg);
    reg = fopen(ARQ_REG,"w");
    fprintf ("%d", num_reg);
    fclose(reg);



    printf("Introduza o seu Nome (Primeiro e Ultimo) : "); gets(p->Nome);
    printf("Introduza o numero da sala que quer reservar:  "); scanf("%d", &p->Sala);
    printf("Introduza a partir de que horas quer reservar a sala (HH:MM): "); scanf("%2d:%2d",&p->Hora_inicio , &p->Minuto_inicio);
    printf("Introduza ate que horas quer reservar a sala (HH:MM): "); scanf("%2d:%2d", &p->Hora_fim , &p->Minuto_fim);
    p -> Status = ' ';
    p -> numero_registo = num_reg;
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");


}
```

Comment: `gets(p->Nome);` could make your program crash if the input is too long – you should pretty much never use that function –, but apart from that, I can't spot anything wrong in this code. I think it might be in some other part of your code.

Comment: This program shouldn't even compile.  You are not supplying the file handle in your calls to `fscanf` and `fprintf`.

Comment: @thejh It's not because of the gets(), it was working before I implemented the new file. My input for gets() wont have more than 20 characters

Comment: @paddy I edited and posted the header file. The file handle was defined earlier in the header file.

Comment: Your `fscanf` call is still erroneous, please check this reference page for it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: Do you call `Numero_Registo()` in the beginning?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, in my main I call it and only then I call Ler_Pessoa()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted source code, the fscanf() and the fprintf() are called without the file pointer . Changing it to

```
fscanf( reg, "%d", &num_reg );
```

and

```
fprintf( reg, "%d", num_reg );
```

could be all.